# Ultra320 SCSI RAID card can this do tape drives

Tags: scsi

I have the following SCSI card:

Adaptec ASR-2200S 64-bit/66MHz Ultra320 SCSI RAID controller

http://www.scsi4me.com/adaptec-asr-2200s-64-bit-66mhz-ultra320-scsi-raid-controller.html

It talks about all the raid modes and whatnot, Number of devices
Up to 30 SCSI devices (15 per channel)

However it does not states if this card can only do HDDs or can be other SCSI devices attached to it.

I tried to attach a Tandberg MLR1 SCSI tape device, it has the same adapter but it does not see it and the CPU on the card heats up.

Comment: Did you install a terminator?

Answer (score 0):

A *RAID controller* usually only supports HDDs, unless tape etc is explicitly mentioned in the specs or in the manual.

The 2200S's [manual](http://download.adaptec.com/pdfs/installation_guides/2120s_2200s_ig.pdf) mentions support for tape and optical drives.

Make sure you terminate each channel properly when they're in use.